# Are there any nicely factoring cubic equations with the same first three coefficients?

Tags: functions

For example is there a factorable equation of the form $(x+1)^3+c$ where $c\neq 0$, more generally is there a factorable equation of the form $(x+a)^{n}+c$ again with the condition that $c\neq0$, but also $n>2$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the same first three coefficients ". If you expand, $(x+1)^3+c=x^3+3x^2+3x+1+c$, where the first three coefficients aren't exactly the same...

Comment: @zipirovich I mean if you subtract one cubic equation from the other can you just have a constant.

Answer (score 0):

For $c \ne 0$ the equation $(x+a)^n + c = 0$ has exactly one real root if $n$ is odd, and two or no roots if $n$ is even and $c \lt 0\,$, $c \gt 0$ respectively. Therefore, there is no factorization possible in linear (real) factors for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: How about factorising into 3 brackets though, would rather not trial and error to find out its impossible.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear but I mean factorable into three brackets, (x+a)(x+b)(x+c) where a, b, c are integers

Comment: @JoshuaFarrell That's not possible for any $n \ge 3\,$. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick answer — just showing some possibilities, but certainly far from complete. Since $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$, pick $c$ to be a perfect cube, and you'll have a nicely factorable expression. The same trick works for all odd powers $n$.